# Why didnt' jQuery mobile enhance elements in a div after i call enhanceWithin()?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am learning how to render mobile web page using jQuery mobile, coding on jsfiddle.
When I follow the way shown in [jQuery mobile document](http://api.jquerymobile.com/enhanceWithin/) to enhance appended elements after web page loaded, the result seems like that enhanceWithin method of jQuery mobile didn't work properly.

I am wondering what's wrong with my code? Or this was caused by jsFiddle?
Maybe it couldn't emulate in some situation?

This is my html code:

```
<div data-role="page">
<div data-role="header" data-position='fixed'>
    <a href="#" id="back" data-role="back" data-rel="back">Back</a>
    <div id="head">Title</div>
</div>
<div id="content" data-role="content">
    <ul id="items" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        <li><a href='#'>Sony TV</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Samsung Note 3</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>ASUS zenfone</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="insert">
    </div>
<div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position='fixed'>
        <div id="foot">copy right.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Styles

```
#head{
    font-size:35px;
    height:100%;
    line-height:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
#foot{
    font-size:30px;
    height:100%;
    line-height:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Scripts:

```
$("#items").append("<li><a href='#'>Sony Z3</a></li>")
.append("<li><a href='#'>Test</a></li>").listview("refresh");

var ctx =
"<ul id='newlistview' data-role='listview' data-inset='true'>" +
    "<li><a href='#'>Line 1</a></li>" +
    "<li><a href='#'>Line 2</a></li>" +

"</ul>";

$("#insert").append(ctx).enhanceWithin();
/*
$('#newlistview').listview({
   inset:true
});
*/
```

Finally, the render result from [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wwsq9odg/2/)

The result I expect to show is as well as the result made by calling .listview({options}) in the block commented.

But I just can't make it with enhanceWithin() method, which I intend to enhance huger code block with many widgets later.

Comment: try (appendTo) instead of (append). any difference? --- http://api.jquerymobile.com/enhanceWithin/

Comment: Do you mean code like $(ctx).appendTo("#insert").enhanceWithin() ?
Seems like it doesn't work either.
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wwsq9odg/3/)

Comment: It works just fine, you just forgot to refresh the list -- http://jsfiddle.net/bqho8yLo/. You are using 1.3 so as the answer below says you need to use trigger create. That works in 1.4 too

Comment: try this demo because i appended to the page instead of the content  -- http://jsfiddle.net/th71jv9x/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/wwsq9odg/4/)

Your code should work fine in `1.4.x`.

Use `.trigger('create')` in 1.3.x (and below) instead of `.enhanceWithin()`

Comment: Thank you!!
And after I fixed my settings to 1.4.2 with correct syntax, it works either.
[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/wwsq9odg/5/) here to provide scratch up code for other practioner like me.

Comment: Great!! :) Bear in mind also that `div#content` is not closed and can cause other issues.

Comment: @youjenlee -- you dont need a div in the content you can append straight to it like this  --- $("#content").append(ctx).enhanceWithin();

Comment: Thanks all of you. Here's the [final version of scratch up code](http://jsfiddle.net/wwsq9odg/9/) for enhancing widgets.